# C++ lambda as std::function in template function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

Let's say we have this simplified version of my code:

```cpp
template<typename R>
R Context::executeTransient(std::function<R(VkCommandBuffer)> const &commands) {
    ...
    R result = commands(commandBuffer);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

I tried to pass a lambda function as a parameter to the function `Context::executeTransient()` but it works only if I explicitly assign the lambda to a specific `std::function` type. This works:

```cpp
std::function<int(VkCommandBuffer)> f = [](VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer) {
    printf("Test execution");
    return 1;
};
context.executeTransient(f);
```

The example above works but I'd like to achieve the example below because of aesthetic reasons and don't know if this is even possible:

```cpp
context.executeTransient([](VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer) {
    printf("Test execution");
    return 1;
});
```

My only requirement is that `Context::executeTransient()` should accept lambdas and functions with a templated return type and input argument with some specific type e.g. `VkCommandBuffer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply as follows ?

```
template <typename F>
auto Context::executeTransient (F const & commands) {
    ...
    auto result = commands(commandBuffer);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

This way your method accept both standard functions and lambdas (without converting them to standard functions, that is preferable, from the performance point of view (as far as I know)) and the return type is deduced from the use (`auto`).

In you need to know the `R` type inside the method, you can apply `decltype()` to `result`

```
     auto result = commands(commandBuffer);

     using R = decltype(result);
```

If you need to know the `R` type as template parameter of the method, its a little more complex because involve `std::declval()` and, unfortunately, add redundancy

```
template <typename F,
          typename R = decltype(std::declval<F const &>()(commandBuffer))>
R Context::executeTransient (F const & commands) {
    ...
    R result = commands(commandBuffer);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The first code snippet works perfectly if I put the implementation in the header. The third one would also work if `commandBuffer` wasn't a local variable. Is there any workaround besides copying the implementation in the header?

Comment: @batthomas - Suggestion: ever (**ever**) put the implementation of templates (classes/structs, functions, methods) in the header. Isn't strictly necessary but usually avoid a lot of troubles. More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)